# PROXY NO AXIOS NODEJS

Tags: node.js

Como faço para colocar proxy em request no axios? Já tentei de tudo mas não estou conseguindo.

```
axios.post('localhost:3000', postdata, 
    {
        headers: headers
    },
    {
        proxy: 'http://minhaproxy:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010'
    })
    .then((res) => { 
        console.log("ok") 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, boa noite amigo! Você não colocou o proxy da maneira correta, você deve colocar dentro do mesmo `JSON` em que se encontra os headers, ficando assim:

```
axios.post('localhost:3000', postdata,
    {
        headers: headers,
        proxy: {
            host: 'http://minhaproxy:@proxy.crawlera.com',
            port: 8010
        }
    }
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("ok")
    }
```

Comment: Muti obrigado, funcionou aqui.

Comment: Por nada, caso seja a resposta correta, marque-a como correta para que as outras pessoas que possuem o mesmo problema virem aqui.